# How to make offline voice calls between Android phone and PC?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I want to communicate with my brother who has android using my PC over bluetooth or Wi-Fi (offline), is that possible?

Comment: Use this kind of Google search: "how to make wifi calls without internet?". This would show you the right webpages. You need to look for a VoIP server and an SIP client for your solution.

Comment: I did. The problem is I only find methods between two phones not between a one and a PC.

Comment: You would have to use something that isn't phone number based that also works on both pc and mobile. Example is that Facebook messenger might do this as its on both pc and mobile. Etc.